# What are the concerns for exposing an api key from a service?

Tags: javascript, security, geocoding, api-key

A lot of sites use an api key for access to their services. A prime example is [MapQuest's geocoding service](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/). Prior to using their service, you are required to sign up to get an assigned api key.

An example of querying with the key:

```
5-box address format: JSON Request

http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&inFormat=json&json={"location":{"street": "1090 N Charlotte St","city":"Lancaster","state":"PA","postalCode":"17603"}}
```

Are there any security concerns if the key is exposed clientside (ie, through javascript)? In this particular instance, it's useful to do the geocoding clientside to avoid the unnecessary load on the server. One problem might be that someone else can use that same key for their own purpose or maybe spam the service until the key is locked.

Comment: I think you pretty much answered your own question here. If the key is just to perform rate-limiting, then the only risk is them using your quota; obviously if it has access to read or write private data somewhere, that's a whole different kettle of fish.